# Access IntelliJ IDEA via the command-line on macOS

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, command-line, terminal

The [JetBrains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains) company provides the [Toolbox App](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/) as a way to automatically install, update, and launch [IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) and other such products. This generally works well for me.

Today I tried to use the command-line interface to IntelliJ IDEA to use their new LightEdit feature. [Their support page](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/04/lightedit-mode/) says on the command line I can do this:

> `idea whatever.java`

…to open the LightEdit code editor.

But when I execute that line in [Terminal.app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(macOS)), I get this error:

> zsh: command not found: idea

➥ What do I need to do on macOS to access IntelliJ IDEA via the command-line?

If found this page, [*Installing IntelliJ IDEA*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/installation-guide.html). It mentions “IntelliJ IDEA command-line launchers” for standalone installation on Windows OS but says nothing about doing so via Toolbox App nor macOS.

Comment: This helped me, https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/enable-shell-scripts-for-the-jetbrains-toolbox-app

Answer (score 6):

See the [Shell scripts generated by the Toolbox App](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html#toolbox) section:

Generate shell scripts
Open the Toolbox App and click The screw nut icon in the top right corner.

1. In the Toolbox App Settings, enable Generate shell scripts.
2. If necessary, change the shell scripts location.

[image]

See also [Open a file in the LightEdit mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/lightedit-mode.html#lightedit_open_file_modes)
.

Comment: I followed your instructions. But no script yet created. How do I get IntelliJ to generate those scripts?

Comment: FYI… I tried again today on an M1 MacBook Pro. I found that option in the Toolbox, used that exact path `/usr/local/bin` and clicked the *Apply* button. But no scripts appeared. I tried launching and quitting IntelliJ, but no scripts appeared. I tried restarting the Mac, but no scripts appeared.

Comment: Script generation is working for me when using `~/bin` instead of `usr/local/bin`. I created `~/bin` manually and added it to PATH in my `.zshrc`.